# How to delete a virsh pool without volumegroup?

Tags: lvm, virsh

My virsh version

```
0.9.12.3
```

I created a Volume Group Pool via virsh.

```
virsh pool-define-as vg1 logical --source-name vg --target /dev/vg
```

Bad thing is, that /dev/vg does not exist, I made a typo.

I tried to delete the pool by

```
virsh pool-delete vg
```

which resulted in

```
error: Failed to delete pool vg1
error: internal error Child process (/sbin/vgremove -f vg) unexpected exit status 5:   Volume group "vg" not found
```

so how do I remove this misconfigured pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can delete a pool without VolumeGroup like this:

The files are stored in

```
/etc/libvirt/storage
```

as XML files. Just delete them.

Comment: If the pool was created in a user-session, the pool might be located in `$HOME/.config/libvirt/storage` instead.