# virsh pool storage basics

Tags: command-line, virtual-machine, kvm, storage, virsh

How or where were these pools created?  Where are configuration files?

```
$ virsh pool-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart 
-------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes       
 Downloads            active     yes       


$ virsh pool-info Downloads
Name:           Downloads
UUID:           fdbe7407-67c4-405d-8e46-9c2695a8b353
State:          running
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      yes
Capacity:       219.88 GiB
Allocation:     34.87 GiB
Available:      185.01 GiB


$ virsh pool-info default
Name:           default
UUID:           cb72b02e-b436-4ec9-9460-d297744c4c69
State:          running
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      yes
Capacity:       219.88 GiB
Allocation:     34.95 GiB
Available:      184.93 GiB
```

I believe that the pools were created by the `virt-manager` GUI.

Is there free space on `default`?  I think that the `Downloads` pool is probably superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Here they [are](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156411/17056):

```
$ ll /etc/libvirt/storage
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 14 00:39 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Nov 12 14:22 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 00:39 autostart/
-rw------- 1 root root  538 Nov 12 14:22 default.xml
-rw------- 1 root root  541 Nov 14 00:39 Downloads.xml
```

actual files:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/libvirt/storage/default.xml 
<!--
WARNING: THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED FILE. CHANGES TO IT ARE LIKELY TO BE
OVERWRITTEN AND LOST. Changes to this xml configuration should be made using:
  virsh pool-edit default
or other application using the libvirt API.
-->

<pool type='dir'>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>cb72b02e-b436-4ec9-9460-d297744c4c69</uuid>
  <capacity unit='bytes'>0</capacity>
  <allocation unit='bytes'>0</allocation>
  <available unit='bytes'>0</available>
  <source>
  </source>
  <target>
    <path>/var/lib/libvirt/images</path>
  </target>
</pool>


$ sudo cat /etc/libvirt/storage/Downloads.xml 
<!--
WARNING: THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED FILE. CHANGES TO IT ARE LIKELY TO BE
OVERWRITTEN AND LOST. Changes to this xml configuration should be made using:
  virsh pool-edit Downloads
or other application using the libvirt API.
-->

<pool type='dir'>
  <name>Downloads</name>
  <uuid>fdbe7407-67c4-405d-8e46-9c2695a8b353</uuid>
  <capacity unit='bytes'>0</capacity>
  <allocation unit='bytes'>0</allocation>
  <available unit='bytes'>0</available>
  <source>
  </source>
  <target>
    <path>/home/thufir/Downloads</path>
  </target>
</pool>
```